# phpexcel import excel with named ranges / pivot tables

Tags: php, phpexcel, named-ranges

I am trying to import excel file using phpexcel library.

The excel file contains `Name Ranges` (which takes data from table in another sheet of same excel file) for data lookup in cells.
I found the function in [phpexcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) library called `getNamedRanges()` which is supposed to list the named ranges from excel file. But it returns an empty array.

**Code:**

```
<?php
$inputFileType = 'Excel2007';
$inputFileName = $uploads_file;
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$objReader->setLoadAllSheets();
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
$ranges = $objPHPExcel->getNamedRanges();
var_dump($ranges);
```

When [phpexcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) tries to lookup data in range, It throws an exception.
Is there any specific method/s in [phpexcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel), that I am missing which considers the named ranges defined in excel while formula calculation?

Comment: Named ranges should work without issue; but Pivot tables are unsupported in PHPExcel

Comment: You're right. In my recent attempts, I see PHPexcel working fine with named ranges while formula calculation. And the exception I am getting is when PHPexcel tries to lookup data range from pivot table. When I convert pivot table to Defined Named ranges, it executes without any issue.

Just wondering, why pivot table is not supported in PHPexcel.

Comment: Some of the basic logic for pivot tables was developed, so that the pivot data was accessible; but we couldn't get styles for pivots working, and any pivot table that included styles that weren't also used elsewhere in the spreadsheet broke quite spectacularly

Comment: @MarkBaker could you please point me to the place in PhphOffice where I can see implemented parts for Pivot tables? Thanks